# how to import dll in c#

Tags: c#, dll

I have some .dll and .xml(e.g. FarsiLibrary.Resources.dll ,FarsiLibrary.Resources.xml) to use with Persian calender .

how do I import it in my project.

note: I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Look right to related, google, don't ask questions asked before ...

Comment: OK.one question what is that xml file has to do with dll? should I include it too? and how ?
note: I took the code from somebody .

Comment: How about you ask that somebody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Right click on project -> Add Reference -> Browse..." for DLL.
Add existing file for XML.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do following

1. Right click on your project and choose Add Reference.
2. When the dialog comes up,  choose the Browse tab and go find your dll
3. After adding the assembly include that reference in your class or
   form where ever you are going to use

Or you looking for `[DllImport("dll")]`? [More Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dllimport)